# How to programmatically srcoll to the extreme left point in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new to Highcharts so please pardon me. 
Actually, I am using Highcharts (type: column) and the scrollbar is enabled. My requirement is to programmatically select a column which might have already scrolled to the extreme left.

I am able to select the column but now i need to manually scroll there in order to see the selection. Although, I tried setting the extremes using setExtremes() method and redrawing the chart using chart.redraw(). This works fine and I get the selected column in the display area.

But, I would like to know is there a better way of doing the same, so that I need not redraw the entire chart every time.

Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Instead of setting extremes after chart is generated, you can set `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max` in options.

Comment: @Pawel - I assume the question means after the chart is generated, and has been scrolled to the right.

Comment: Yes, but to change extremes, you need to use `setExtremes`. To avoid redraw, the only way is to generate chart in time range where searched column is placed.

Comment: Right. The scrollbar itself sets extremes and redraws the chart to, doesn't it?

Comment: this is simple example http://jsfiddle.net/roytirthadeep/wqwq5g8c/6/ 

i have a similar requirement .... here I am not doing any redraw or setExtremes right now... could you please suggest....

Comment: @jlbriggs as I remember, when setting min&max you don't get extra redraw. Anyway, it looks like selecting point by some action, so my suggestion won't work. @Roy - in your case I don't see better solution than calling `setExtremes()`.